# Facebook/Twitter API getting callback when user deleted a post?

Tags: facebook, twitter

is it possible to detect if a user has deleted a Facebook/Twitter post, posted by an API? Is there a callback or a call to check that status, say in a weeks time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook and Twitter do not "push" from their API.  In order to track whether a particular user had deleted a post, you would need to check their timeline/wall on a regular basis.  Each time you check the timeline, you would have to check the unique message IDs to see if a message that was there the last time you checked is now absent.

Even this will not be perfect.  But it's about as good as you can do within the constraints of the APIs.